# Create histogram in ggplot with both x and y variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am hoping to make a histogram which shows the distribution of individuals who have anxiety (y axis) across age groups (x axis). I am unsure how to properly code for this since I want to include 2 variables on a single graph. The anxiety variable (MOD_SEV_ANX) is binary (1 if have it, 0 if no anxiety), and age is continuous. I've included an MRE to try and illustrate what I'm attempting to do.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

#Here is the data
data=structure(list(AGE = c(40L, 23L, 24L, 18L, 30L, 33L, 32L, 63L, 
22L, 24L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 27L, 20L, 65L, 25L, 36L, 59L, 47L, 44L, 
31L, 56L, 40L, 53L, 54L, 30L, 23L, 27L, 28L, 38L, 33L, 42L, 39L, 
23L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 24L, 44L), MOD_SEV_ANX = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
40L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=AGE,y=mean(MOD_SEV_ANX)))+ 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 3)
```

When I try and run this bottom line of code I receive the following error: "Error: stat_bin() can only have an x or y aesthetic." How can I address this? Thanks!

Comment: That's a bar chart, not a histogram, try `ggplot(etc) + geom_col()`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you for pointing that out. Sorry it was confusing to include that graphic. I am interested in making a histogram, not a bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three choices, facet it, plot side by side or if you really mean it side by side plus reorient to show histogram vertically.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data,aes(x=AGE))+
   geom_histogram(bins = 10)+
   facet_grid(~MOD_SEV_ANX)+
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data,aes(x=AGE,group=MOD_SEV_ANX, fill=factor(MOD_SEV_ANX)))+
   geom_histogram(position="dodge", bins = 10)+ 
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data,aes(x=AGE,group=MOD_SEV_ANX, fill=factor(MOD_SEV_ANX)))+
   geom_histogram(position="dodge", bins = 10)+ 
   coord_flip() +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much

Comment: If that solved it please mark the checkmark for answered

Comment: Will do! Sorry forgot about that.